# How to do nmds ordination and plotting in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 350 species data from 157 samples. The data is collected over different years within different eco-regions. I am trying to do NMDS ordination in ggplot. But I am not able to plot it in ggplot. I keep getting error. I don't know how to plot these many species from different sampling sites, with different year and different eco-regions.
Can anyone help with ggplot plotting. How can I plot this big dataset, so that I am able to tell difference between sample sites over years by ecoregion. Any help would be great. As, I am not proficient in R.

This is how data is arranged: 157 observation of 350 variables

Column1: site name

Column2: Year

Column 3: Ecoregion as numerical (1-6)

Column 4-350: Individual species

Here is the script I used for calculating NMDS

```
sp= read.csv(file.choose())
sp2 <- sp[, 4:350]

rownames(sp2)=sp[,1]

#transform:
sp.hel<-decostand(sp2,method="hellinger")

#nmds
nmds<-metaMDS(sp.hel,autotransform = F)
#here, solution didnt reached

#increasing stress trial by 300, solution reached
nmds<-metaMDS(sp.hel,k=2,trymax=300,autotransform = F)

#ordination
ordiplot(nmds)
ordiplot(nmds,type="t")

#extract NMDS scores (x and y coordinates)
data.scores = as.data.frame(scores(nmds))



#add columns to data frame 
data.scores$site <- rownames(data.scores)
data.scores$Year = sp$Year
data.scores$Ecoregion = sp$Ecoregion
head(data.scores)

gglpot
xx = ggplot(data.scores, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2)) + 
geom_point(size = 4, aes( shape = Ecoregion, colour = Year))+ 
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold"), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 12), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face ="bold", colour ="black"), 
    legend.position = "right", axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14, colour = "black"), 
    legend.title = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", face = "bold"), 
    panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA,       size = 1.2),
    legend.key=element_blank()) + 
labs(x = "NMDS1", colour = "sample", y = "NMDS2", shape = "Type")  + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#E69F00")) 

xx
plot(xx)
```

Data:

```
structure(
  list(
    ï..Site.name = c(
      "Hamma Hamma River 21",
      "Griffin Creek 21",
      "Trapper Creek 21",
      "Twenty-Five Mile Creek 21",
      "Ellsworth Creek 21",
      "Twin Creek 21",
      "Laughingwater Creek 21",
      "Little Pend Orielle River 21",
      "Hamma Hamma River 211",
      "Griffin Creek 211",
      "Trapper Creek 211",
      "Twenty-Five Mile Creek 211",
      "Ellsworth Creek 211",
      "Twin Creek 211",
      "Laughingwater Creek 211",
      "Little Pend Orielle River 211",
      "Panjab Creek 211",
      "Asotin Creek, North Fork 211",
      "Cle Elum River below Hyas Lake 211",
      "Umtanum Creek 211",
      "Asotin Creek, North Fork 212",
      "Cle Elum River 212",
      "Deadman Creek, South Fork 212",
      "Ellsworth Creek 212",
      "Griffin Creek 212",
      "Hamma Hamma River 212",
      "Laughingwater Creek 212",
      "Little Pend Orielle River 212",
      "Marble Creek 212",
      "Panjab Creek 212",
      "Poormans Creek 212",
      "Sullivan Creek, North Fork 212",
      "Trapper Creek 212",
      "Twenty-Five Mile Creek 212",
      "Twin Creek 212",
      "Umtanum Creek 212",
      "Umtanum Creek 213",
      "Asotin Creek, North Fork 213",
      "Deadman Creek, South Fork 213",
      "Ellsworth Creek 213",
      "Griffin Creek 213",
      "Hamma Hamma River 213",
      "Laughingwater Creek 213",
      "Little Pend Orielle River 213",
      "Marble Creek 213",
      "Panjab Creek 213",
      "Poormans Creek 213",
      "Sullivan Creek, North Fork 213",
      "Middle Fork Teanaway River 213",
      "Trapper Creek 213",
      "Twenty-Five Mile Creek 213",
      "Twin Creek 213",
      "Little Pend Orielle River 214",
      "Twenty-Five Mile Creek 214",
      "Poormans Creek 214",
      "Twin Creek 214",
      "Laughingwater Creek 214",
      "Hamma Hamma River 214",
      "Marble Creek 214",
      "Asotin Creek, North Fork 214",
      "Griffin Creek 214",
      "Trapper Creek 214",
      "Cummings Creek 214",
      "Middle Fork Teanaway River 214",
      "Ellsworth Creek 214",
      "Deadman Creek, South Fork 214",
      "Sullivan Creek, North Fork 214",
      "Umtanum Creek 214",
      "Asotin Creek, North Fork 215",
      "Cummings Creek 215",
      "Deadman Creek, South Fork 215",
      "Ellsworth Creek 215",
      "Griffin Creek 215",
      "Hamma Hamma River 215",
      "Laughingwater Creek 215",
      "Little Pend Orielle River 215",
      "Marble Creek 215",
      "Poormans Creek 215",
      "Sullivan Creek, North Fork 215",
      "Middle Fork Teanaway River 215",
      "Trapper Creek 215",
      "Twenty-Five Mile Creek 215",
      "Twin Creek 215",
      "Umtanum Creek 215",
      "Deadman Creek, South Fork 216",
      "Little Pend Orielle River 216",
      "Asotin Creek, North Fork 216",
      "Sullivan Creek, North Fork 216",
      "Cummings Creek 216",
      "Griffin Creek 216",
      "Poormans Creek 216",
      "Twenty-Five Mile Creek 216",
      "Marble Creek 216",
      "Middle Fork Teanaway River 216",
      "Umtanum Creek 216",
      "Laughingwater Creek 216",
      "Trapper Creek 216",
      "Twin Creek 216",
      "Hamma Hamma River 216",
      "Ellsworth Creek 216",
      "Deadman Creek, South Fork 217",
      "Little Pend Orielle River 217",
      "Asotin Creek, North Fork 217",
      "Sullivan Creek, North Fork 217",
      "Cummings Creek 217",
      "Griffin Creek 217",
      "Poormans Creek 217",
      "Twenty-Five Mile Creek 217",
      "Marble Creek 217",
      "Middle Fork Teanaway River 217",
      "Umtanum Creek 217",
      "Laughingwater Creek 217",
      "Trapper Creek 217",
      "Twin Creek 217",
      "Hamma Hamma River 217",
      "Ellsworth Creek 217",
      "Deadman Creek, South Fork 218",
      "Little Pend Orielle River 218",
      "Asotin Creek, North Fork 218",
      "Sullivan Creek, North Fork 218",
      "Cummings Creek 218",
      "Griffin Creek 218",
      "Poormans Creek 218",
      "Twenty-Five Mile Creek 218",
      "Marble Creek 218",
      "Middle Fork Teanaway River 218",
      "Umtanum Creek 218",
      "Laughingwater Creek 218",
      "Trapper Creek 218",
      "Twin Creek 218",
      "Hamma Hamma River 218",
      "Ellsworth Creek 218",
      "Asotin Creek, North Fork 219",
      "Cummings Creek 219",
      "Deadman Creek, South Fork 219",
      "Griffin Creek 219",
      "Little Pend Orielle River 219",
      "Marble Creek 219",
      "Poormans Creek 219",
      "Sullivan Creek, North Fork 219",
      "Middle Fork Teanaway River 219",
      "Trapper Creek 219",
      "Twenty-Five Mile Creek 219",
      "Umtanum Creek 219",
      "Ellsworth Creek 219",
      "Laughingwater Creek 219",
      "Hamma Hamma River 219",
      "Twin Creek 219",
      "Ellsworth Creek 22",
      "Griffin Creek 22",
      "Laughingwater Creek 22",
      "Trapper Creek 22",
      "Middle Fork Teanaway River 22",
      "Coleman Creek 22",
      "Asotin Creek, North Fork 22",
      "Hamma Hamma River 22",
      "Deadman Creek, South Fork 22"
    ),
    Year = c(
      2010L,
      2010L,
      2010L,
      2010L,
      2010L,
      2010L,
      2010L,
      2010L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2011L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2012L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2013L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2014L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2015L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2016L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2017L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2018L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2019L,
      2020L,
      2020L,
      2020L,
      2020L,
      2020L,
      2020L,
      2020L,
      2020L,
      2020L
    ),
    Ecoregion = c(
      "Southwest",
      "Northwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "Southwest",
      "Northwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "East",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "Southwest",
      "Northwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "East",
      "Southwest",
      "Northwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "Northwest",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "East",
      "East",
      "Southwest",
      "Northwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "East",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "Northwest",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "East",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "Northwest",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "East",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "Northwest",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "East",
      "East",
      "East",
      "Northwest",
      "East",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Northwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Southwest",
      "Central",
      "Central",
      "East",
      "Southwest",
      "East"
    ),
    Achnanthes.nodosa = c(
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      4L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      9L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      3L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      32L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      4L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L
    ),
    Achnanthidium.crassum.Achnanthidium.rivulare.Achnanthidium.deflexum = c(
      2L,
      42L,
      0L,
      0L,
      13L,
      0L,
      8L,
      0L,
      9L,
      98L,
      2L,
      0L,
      98L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      19L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      53L,
      29L,
      9L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      8L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      2L,
      73L,
      174L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      14L,
      0L,
      16L,
      4L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      3L,
      0L,
      3L,
      2L,
      0L,
      0L,
      48L,
      0L,
      0L,
      7L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      81L,
      3L,
      1L,
      2L,
      0L,
      0L,
      14L,
      0L,
      6L,
      23L,
      2L,
      1L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      89L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      1L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      31L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      2L,
      2L,
      14L,
      0L,
      54L,
      0L,
      5L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      211L,
      0L,
      1L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      2L,
      0L,
      0L,
      31L,
      0L,
      3L,
      3L,
      451L,
      0L,
      0L,
      11L,
      0L,
      0L,
      6L,
      0L,
      0L,
      28L,
      1L,
      0L,
      13L,
      3L,
      474L,
      1L,
      2L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L
    ),
    Achnanthidium.eutrophilum = c(
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      14L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      99L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      2L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      2L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      4L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L
    ),
    Achnanthidium.exiguum = c(
      0L,
      2L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      6L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      3L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      7L,
      0L,
      0L,
      3L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      3L,
      0L,
      9L,
      1L,
      3L,
      0L,
      0L,
      2L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      2L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      3L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      2L,
      0L,
      5L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      2L
    ),
    Achnanthidium.gracillimum = c(
      0L,
      0L,
      8L,
      0L,
      0L,
      3L,
      0L,
      4L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      17L,
      0L,
      0L,
      12L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      6L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      22L,
      0L,
      4L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      1L,
      4L,
      3L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      4L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      14L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      2L,
      1L
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-157L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

Comment: Hi @Malik, could you please provide us some data using `dput(sp)`?

Comment: From your description it seems like your data is in wide format: every cell in columns 4-350 represent an observation. The ggplot2 packages works well with data in a long format, so I'd suggest using `tidyr::pivot_longer()` to reshape it.

Comment: Thank you @teunbrand. I will check this function to see if this works.

Comment: Hi, @Quinten. Let me check how can I import this data. New to this formus. Don't know to use all these functions.

Comment: @Malik, you should call dput(sp) in your console and copy paste the output in your question above.